# Fix - Keyboard moving the entire collection view up leaving up white space

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

In my `Collection ViewController` I have `Collection View Cell` and `textField` in them. Every time I press on `textField` and keyboard shows up the `view` is moved up leaving white space...

**Before keyboard is showed**
[everything is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgB7y.png)

**After keyboard is shown**
[cell layout is up...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hi8r.png) and you cannot see the entire cell content.

I tried one answer solution below and I got this: [black view on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYSPO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add observers for when the keyboard shows and hides and shift your views accordingly:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let newYOrigin = CGFloat(100) // or whatever new value you want
        self.yourView.frame.origin.y = newYOrigin
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let newYOrigin = CGFloat(0) // or whatever new value you want
        self.yourView.frame.origin.y = newYOrigin
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this sort of works because yes the cell is has proper layout after the keyboard disappears but when keyboard is shown at first I do get a black view on top covering some part of the view. See the question image I edited

Comment: Okay I did get it right when I set newOrigin to 1 ... Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sometimes only when I turn off the keyboard by pressing command + K this doesn't work. What is the problem does this work only when "return" is pressed or what ?